# android web app can not full screen when I add the viewport meta

Tags: android, web, fullscreen

I created an android web app.I filled the address via the mobile's virtual keyboard and then pressed the "enter" key to accessed it with the android broswer,however sometimes the web app can't full screen when the virtual key hide.It seems cause by the viewport meta tag insert into the head tag.

how to solve the problem?